# body tag overflow (auto, visible?)

Tags: css

How come the body element doesn't use `overflow-y: auto` yet it still behaves the same way?

I believe it defaults to `visible`, but how does it actually work?

Comment: there is not need to use `overflow:auto` property in `<body>` unless you use 'overfloe:hidden' to it because by default overflow is visible in body

Comment: There's basically nothing other than the body to be displayed, so the `visible` value makes no sense. Thus, it probably defaults to `auto`.

Comment: I don't follow. The default value is `visible`. I'm wondering why `<body>` doesn't need `overflow-y: auto` like other elements do, in order to make it scrollable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `body` (and `html`) tag are special cases, being at the root of the DOM hierarchy, and browsers must render these as if they were set to `auto`.

This is outlined in the [`overflow` documentation on W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow) back in CSS 2.1:

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the 'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport, if the value on the root element is 'visible'. The 'visible' value when used for the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'. The element from which the value is propagated must have a used value for 'overflow' of 'visible'.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know a resource that lists all the special cases for `<html>` and `<body>` tags? I already encountered a couple, such as `<html>`s width and height corresponding to the viewport. It'd be nice if there's a single place I can go to get a deeper understanding instead of having to scan through W3 or stackoverflow as I come across them.

Comment: No, I don't. I am pretty sure it is just the width/height on html, and a position static on the body, aside from the overflow quirks. I think body has a default margin, but that is obvious. I don't know of any other cases where the default values are overridden or handled differently, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You could start [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-970131) which is where I got started with my answer.  Also [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/) for documentation on all W3C standards.  Looks like there have been revisions added to the DOM documentation as recently as November 2015, so should be reliable

Comment: On Chrome 106, if `<html>` element has an `overflow:hidden`, setting `overflow:initial` on the `<body>` element is computed as `overflow:visible`. If I change that to `overflow:auto` as suggested, the behavior changes. So, at least on Chrome 106 desktop, `visible` seems to be the default for `<body>` if the value of the root element is NOT `visible` (does not violate W3C).

Answer (score 5):

Had to look into some white papers for this one.  The `body` element is a special element in the DOM and has some "pseudo-immutable" properties that I'll get to in the answer.

First off, [W3C position documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-970131#<BODY>) points out the following:

> The BODY element defines a special implicit container having the
>   following properties:
>
> - Its position, width, height and clipping region are determined by the
>     User Agent, and may not be modified.
> - It establishes a coordinate
>     system for child elements, with the origin at the document's logical
>     top, left corner.

Knowing this, we dig into what the defaults for these properties are for the body.  The `position` is set to `static` which ends up making its `height` and `width` properties inherited from the parent `html` element.

I found this documentation a little bit strange in that I could change the value of the `height` on the body element and set a border around it:

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #1db3e7;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis dolor eget risus ultrices mattis. Maecenas dolor est, malesuada ac efficitur sed, cursus quis nibh. Sed vulputate arcu molestie ipsum pharetra hendrerit vitae ac mauris. Duis quis purus quis elit varius convallis. Proin dictum nec purus eget accumsan. Suspendisse dignissim sollicitudin risus. Praesent nec quam in nisl dictum lobortis. Maecenas ultricies purus nec turpis egestas, ultrices elementum arcu pretium. Vestibulum id diam eu arcu placerat ultrices. Donec porta augue magna, eu tristique dui sodales in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

</body>
```

However, no matter what `position` and `overflow` I set, the text always has the capability to go beyond this border.  This speaks to the immutable-ness of the `position` property, but it did make me question that statement for `height`.

Finally, the `html` element is what is actually making the scrollbar appear, based on the `body`'s width and height dependency on the `html` element and its default `position` value.  The first entry to controlling the page's scroll would be on the first child element of the `body` element.